# replace array elements with elements of a list in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a NumPy array and I converted it into a matrix called string_matrix where each element is a string.
Now I want to convert each element in string_matrix to letters. The number in matrix are the index of the list alp.
So I want this output : `string_matrix = [['l' 'i' 'a']['a' 'f' 'b']['u' 'e' 'k']]`

```
alp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",""]
matrix = numpy.array([[11, 8, 0],[0, 5, 1],[20, 4, 10]])
string_matrix = numpy.array(["%.f" % v for v in matrix.reshape(matrix.size)])
string_matrix = string_matrix.reshape(matrix.shape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index into the `alp` list with your `matrix`, you need to make `alp` a numpy array first:

```
numpy.array(alp)[matrix]
```

Output:

```
array([['l', 'i', 'a'],
       ['a', 'f', 'b'],
       ['u', 'e', 'k']], dtype='<U1')
```

This uses numpy's advanced indexing. You can find more details [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.4/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) if you want to read up on it.

Comment: Is it possible to use a loop instead of this numpy's advanced indexing ?

Comment: Yea you can loop over the elements of the matrix and index into alp with its individual elements, rows, or columns. What do you want to loop over?

Comment: Over its individual elements but I solved this problem, thank you